# Почему с типом bool работает оператор new?

Tags: c++

Почему код

```
bool ptr{new bool};
std::cout << ptr;
```

работает, а код

```
int ptr{new int};
std::cout << ptr;
```

не работает?

Comment: потому что указатель может неявно приводится к bool

Comment: а почему с char не работает? он же тоже 1 байт?

Comment: Потому что указатель может неявно приводится к bool, а не к "любому типу размером один байт".

Comment: А почему было сделано так чтобы он кастовался к bool?

Comment: "так сложилось исторически"

Comment: Потому что `if (указатель)` - это удобно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё дело в наличии неявного преобразования типа указателя в `bool`. К `new` это относится только лишь по той причине, что `new` возвращает указатель. А так, конечно, не имеет значения каким образом вы этот указатель получите: можно и функцию вызвать, или просто адрес переменной взять через `&`.

Всё, что неявно преобразуется в `bool` может быть использовано в условных конструкция: `if`, `for`, `while`. Неявное преобразование указателей в булево значение удобно для проверки наличия объекта (т.к. нулевой указатель `nullptr` говорит о том, что указываемого объекта нет). А значит проверка вида `if (ptr != nullptr)` может быть заменена на `if (ptr)`. Такое поведение унаследовалось от Си. Стоит заметить, что в C# или Java такого неявного преобразования нет, и под `if` должно быть явное булево выражение.

Дополнительно к `bool` неявно преобразуются любые стандартные скалярные типы: нулевое значение интерпретируется как `false`, всё остальное как `true`.